# Remove image banner on individual pages?

Tags: 7, media

I have zero experience with Drupal or any other similar systems. I have simply been given access to a Drupal website (that was created by an external company) at work and told to make changes. I have managed to somewhat figure out a few general basic things but having many problems that are making me lose my mind.

My current problem is this: there are a bunch of basic pages with the usual stuff, a side menu, content area, etc. They also have a banner image along the top (created as a field in the content type "basic page"). I need to remove the banner image from just one page. Simple. Or so I thought. I can't seem to figure this out. I tried making the banner image field not required and leaving it empty, but an image still appears.

Any sugestions?

PS. I'm not sure but I think it's Drupal 7 (that's right, I don't even know how to check that).

Comment: About your PS: are you sure you're using Drupal?

Comment: Link to the site, CSS is going to be quickest easiest method, please don't tell me it won't work, just link to the site and let me worry about that, everything is doable but I need to see what it going on first.

Comment: ascoworld.com/services It is the banner image on that page I need to remove, but still keep the banner image on the other pages. Thanks Jeff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the `body` element there are page classes for each "node", and in Drupal every node has a number, called the "nid" or "node id".

The services page nid is 65.

Look at the body element in your browsers inspector (right click, "Inspect"), you'll see something like this for the body:

```
<body class="html not-front not-logged-in one-sidebar sidebar-first page-node page-node- page-node-65 node-type-page i18n-en-gb blue">
```

For every node in the site there is always going to be the `page-node-[node-id]` class, e.g. `page-node-65`

By "banner" I assume you mean the photo of the oil rig? If so you can use the body class and the wrapper on that image:

```
.page-node-65 .cover {
  display: none;
}
```

But - consider this a stop gap solution, you need to figure out how the site is structured/built and try to remove the picture/banner from being there in the first place.

Comment: Jeff! You are the man! I cannot thank you enough. My hero. My everything.

8 hours today trying to solve this and you come along like Superman and save the day. I was about to quit my job and live under a bridge. Thank you! I wish I could buy you a beer, but take my massive thanks instead!

Comment: Bridges are for trolls, not good places. I think you can accept the answer, or vote it up or something, that would be great. I'm not superman, just a Drupal dev casually watching the Olympics and trying to be of help :)

Answer (score 1):

These banners will almost comes from Blocks section.

1. Goto `"www.yoursite.com/admin/structure/block"` try searching for
   block name
2. Click on `Configure`
3. In the Visibility section -> Check this `"All pages except those listed"`
4. Enter `<page URL>`
5. Click on `Save block`

Attached image for reference.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!

It doesn't appear to be a block. The only way I can get to it is by going to structure > content types > basic page > manage fields and it is in that list. I can delete it but don't want to as it will remove the banner images from every page, where as I just want to remove it from one page.

Comment: That is not the solution. Either you can go and remove those images in that particular node or you need to hide it through CSS.

Comment: I can't remove it through CSS as this would remove it on all pages (as they have the same class/id). Sorry for my ignorance, but can you tell me what a node is and how to remove it through there? Thanks.

Comment: Go to '/admin/content' -> search your title name -> 'Click on Edit' -> delete those images